# Does the <domainService> Tag still work for Silverlight 5 and RIA Services?

Tags: json, silverlight, iis-7.5, wcf-ria-services, endpoint

I am trying to add a JSON endpoint to a WCF RIA Service.

I have read many tutorials on this and I have also watched videos on silverlight.net.

Everywhere I find something on this topic, I am told to use the domainService Tag in web.config.

One code example looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<domainServices>
  <endpoints>
    <add name="JSON" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.JsonEndpointFactory, Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </endpoints>
</domainServices>
<system.serviceModel>
```

**This is not working and there are two issues:**

1. In Visual Studio 2010 the domainService Tag is underlined blue, with the hint, that this is an unexpected tag.
2. In IIS the domainService Tag is producing an unknown element error.

Among others, I have referenced the following DLLs in my web project:

**-Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting**

-Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Tools

-Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.LinqToSql

-System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework

**-System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting**

-System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.OData

-System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server

I also have the WCF RIA Services V1.0 SP2 installed.

I really don't know, how to resolve it. I need help. I have googled and searched excessively.

Thank you.

**This case is solved. Please read my comments to Jeff's answer. You may find some additional information on this problem.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON endpoint is part of the WCF RIA Services Toolkit, not the product itself.  You can get the Toolkit MSI here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26939

However, I recommend pulling the JSON endpoint in through NuGet instead, using the RIAServices.Endpoints package:
http://nuget.org/packages/RIAServices.Endpoints

Here's some more information about the NuGet packages available:
http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2012/12/10/RIA-Services-NuGet-Package-Updates-ndash-Including-Support-for-EntityFramework.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At first, I have installed the NuGet Endpoint package. This installation added the domainService tag with the endpoints json and soap to my web.config. Unfortunately it did not help. The domainService tag was still not excepted by VS 2010. I decided to install the complete WCF RIA Service Toolkit with NuGet. This helped. My SL RIA services have now binary and JSON endpoints. I can invoke them easyliy with the browser or the SL client. You saved me a lot of work, search and frustration. Thanks a lot for this solution.

Comment: Just a hint to others: I had installed the WCF RIA Toolkit manually before. It just didn't work for me. After this I recommend using NuGet, excactly as Jeff told me.

Comment: And my last hint: In the config section of your web.config file, it has to be sectionGroup name="system.serviceModel" AND NOT sectionGroup name="System.ServiceModel". My project does not compile, if it is written in upper case letters. If I use upper case letters, VS 2010 won't compile the domainService Tag. I recognized this now, because the NuGet installation placed the system.serviceModel with lower case letters. After all this, I think this was the only mistake I made, but VS 2010 will not tell you, that you have use lower case letters.

Answer (score 1):

For me the correct way to resolve the issue was adding the following to web.config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.serviceModel">
            <section name="domainServices" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServicesSection, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections> ...
```